# Uploading multipart/form-data is pass and fail randomly

Tags: javascript, ajax, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use following code to upload multipart/form-data to the server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form >
       <input  id="file" type="file" name="file" multiple><br>
    </form>
    <button id="ajax_submit">ajax_submit</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
    $( "#ajax_submit" ).click(function()
    {
      //alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
      var i = 0;
      while (i < document.getElementById('file').files.length)
      {

        var data = new FormData();


    //alert("before" + i);
        data.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[i]);//first string parameter indicate the input field to name for server side
    //alert("after" + i);

        jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/sign',
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          method: 'POST',
          type: 'POST', // For jQuery < 1.9
          success: function(data)
          {
            //alert(data);
          }
        });
        i++;
      }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is when select multiple files at once, it has very low probability to get a successful response when I select one file it has higher probability.

When it get **success** I got following **request and response headers** on Chrome:

```
Genaral
    Request URL:http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/sign
    Request Method:POST
    Status Code:200 
    Remote Address:xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
    Date:Thu, 19 Oct 2017 08:50:08 GMT
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked
    X-Application-Context:application
Request Headers
    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:33274
    Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryOuscIdBAA52VbAZK
    Host:xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080
    Origin:null
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
 Request Payload
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryOuscIdBAA52VbAZK
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="text.pdf"
    Content-Type: application/pdf
```

When I get **failed** I got following **error messages**, **request and response headers** on Safari and Chrome browsers:

**Chrome:**

```
Genaral    
    Request URL:http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/sign
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
    Provisional headers are shown
    Accept:*/*
    Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAmGAPOT6r0Voe5mr
    Origin:null
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryAmGAPOT6r0Voe5mr
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="empty.pdf"
    Content-Type: application/pdf
```

> POST http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/sign net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
>   send  @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 ajax  @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
>   (anonymous)   @   multiplefileHandler.html:26
>   dispatch  @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3 q.handle  @
>   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
>
> POST http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080/sign net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
>   send  @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 ajax  @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
>   (anonymous)   @   multiplefileHandler.html:26
>   dispatch  @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3 q.handle  @   jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3

---

**Safari:**

> Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.
>
> Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server.

---

When I trying to call using Java Apache HTTP client I got following error:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8080 failed to respond
```

Screenshot of activity monitor when I select 8 files and press `ajax_submit` button using Chrome. At that time Chrome only had one tab with above page.
[image]

Comment: while i appreciate the client side errors, i think showing server logs would also be important to debug this issue. connection_refused is a server side error hinting at the server itself not taking the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when there are many requests within few milliseconds, the server gets failed and no one to respond at server side.

**Summary: server-side failure.**